# Random selection of elements of a list with exception

Tags: python

```
import random

a = [1, 2, 5, 3, 4, 5]
b = ["cat", "dog", "horse", "snake", "elephant", "goat"]
```

Hello! I am fairly new to programming. I'm sure it's not a difficult task, but I just can't find the solution.

I need a function in python to store a single random element from list "b" as a new list, but the elements that share the same index with elements from list "a" that are 5 must not be included in the random selection.
So in my example, "horse" and "goat" must not be included in the random selection.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. What have you already tried, and where are you stuck? There are at least three parts to this task: 1) compare `a` and `b` side-by-side, 2) filter `b`, 3) pick from the filtered items. Which do you need help with? If this is homework, please read [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/4518341) For more tips, see [ask]. You can [edit] to add details.

Comment: Related: [filter a list based on values in another list](/q/63785948/4518341), [How can I randomly select an item from a list?](/q/306400/4518341)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension and `random.choice`:

```
import random

a = [1, 2, 5, 3, 4, 5]
b = ["cat", "dog", "horse", "snake", "elephant", "goat"]
c = [random.choice([e for i,e in zip(a,b) if i != 5])]
```

Example output: `['dog']`